# ValueError: could not convert string to float: (Python) And I am sure there is no added str except for necessary dot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

So I'm trying to do this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/esperance-tunis/startseite/verein/3342"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

playername = pageSoup.find_all("div", {"class": "di nowrap"})

playerage = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})

playervalue = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})


Name = []
Ages = []
Value = []

for i in range(0, len(playername), 2):
  Name.append(playername[i].text)

for i in range(0, len(playerage)):
  Ages.append(playerage[i].text)

for i in range(0, len(playervalue) ):
  Value.append(playervalue[i].text)
Age = []
for i in Ages:
  if len(i) == 17:
    Age.append(i)
  elif len(i) == 16:
    Age.append(i)

for i in range(len(Value)):
  Value[i] = re.sub('[^\d\.\ ]', '', Value[i])
  Value[i] = float(Value[i])
```

But then it tells me `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`
Why ? I need to keep the dots so I can locate values that are supposed to be 1 Million, from those that are supposed to be 1 Thousand.

Comment: Tried printing `Value` before `Value[i] = float(Value[i])`?

Comment: I tried it and it fails on the 28th item where Value[i] is the empty string  ```Value[i] = float(Value[i])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: There's an error in the data - print Value just before the loop - the 27, 28, 29th items are ```'€700Th.\xa0', '\xa0', '€550Th.\xa0',``` Your last line could become: ```If Value: Value[i] = float(Value[i])```

Comment: The ValueError exception gives more information than you've shown. After *float:* there will be more information - specifically the data that it is unable to convert. In your case it's an empty string. Note that on the webpage there is no market value stated for Kouadio Brou David Koffi

Comment: Ohhhh I see a Value[i] is empty sorry, and thanks.